# How can I convert a three.js camera to a Revit ViewOrientation3D?

Tags: javascript, c#, three.js, revit-api

I've been trying to take the position, direction and up vector from a three.js camera and apply it to a ViewOrientation3D in Revit. I'm running into a problem where setting the orientation throws this exception.

`Exception thrown: 'Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.ArgumentsInconsistentException' in RevitAPI.dll`

The ViewOrientation3D documentation says this exception is thrown when "The vectors upDirection and forwardDirection are not perpendicular.". Which parameters from the three.js camera do I need to use?

```
ViewOrientation3D orientation = new ViewOrientation3D(threePosition, threeUp, threeDirection);
view.SetOrientation(orientation);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is answered in full by The Building Coder, e.g., discussing how to [Map Forge Viewer Camera Settings back to Revit](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/06/revit-camera-settings-project-plasma-da4r-and-ai.html#2) and [Serialising 3D View Camera Settings](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/10/save-and-restore-3d-view-camera-settings.html#2). Please confirm and share a code snippet showing how you end up using this to solve your issue. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JeremyTammik, I followed this tutorial although bits of it were very useful, although I'm not using Forge, instead plain three.js. Unless calculated I don't automatically get access to a camera target like in Forge. I'd like to use the camera's [world direction](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/Camera.getWorldDirection) if possible. Does this give any ideas as to why I get the exception?

Comment: To elaborate, as soon as my camera in three.js has any up/down tilt it is not accepted in Revit. If the camera in three.js is completely level then Revit accepts it.

Comment: Well, the error message clearly states that the `upDirection` and `forwardDirection` are not perpendicular. You can create perpendicular vectors using simple cross product operations. By calculating XYZ upDirection = viewOrientation3D.UpDirection;
XYZ rightDirection = forwardDirection.CrossProduct(upDirection); as in the post pointed to, you guarantee that they are perpendicular. You question is not on cameras at all; it is simply how to create three mutually perpendicular vectors in the required orientastion.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this :)